# Using OneDrive as "Pipeline" to Move Photos to my PC (but not Store the Photos on OneDrive)

Tags: backup, onedrive, photos

I like that OneDrive can easily sync photos to my desktop Win 10 PC. My PC is my central repository of all my photos. I'm not looking to use OneDrive as the final destination - just a "pipeline" to neatly get my phone's photos to my PC without filling up OneDrive. I don't want to delete the photos from my phone - nor from the destination PC. I just don't want OneDrive to fill-up beyond capacity. Thanks in advance for any thoughts or suggestions.

Comment: Due to the nature of how OneDrive works, what you want is simply not possible. So the answer is going to be: Do not use OneDrive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not try to use Phone Companion which is an app released by Microsoft. We could download it from Windows store. It will sync your mobile photo automatically to PC, and not store it on the app. It is just like the pipeline.

Comment: Thanks Joy - I see that it's experimental - and it requires a bit more "manual" intervention - but it seems like the best possibility at the moment! Thanks Again!

Comment: **UPDATE**  Thanks Joy - I see there is both "Your Phone Companion" and "Photos Companion" - (both by Microsoft) it looks like your suggestion - "Your Phone Companion" is the way to go. I'll check it out and thanks again!